# CTabCtrl ItemAction & ItemState

Tags: c++, mfc

I’ve created my own `CXTabCtrl` that extends `CTabCtrl` and override the `DrawItem` Function.
During the phase of rewriting the `DrawItem` Function, I wasn’t able to differentiate between this two states of `CTabCtrl` Item:

1. `CTabCtrl` item is selected and have focus.
2. `CTabctrl` item is selected but doesn’t have focus.

By focus I mean the Focus rectangle is not drawing. Here are two images that will help identify the two states:

[image: Selected but not focused]    [image: Select & Focus]

Here’s the `DrawItem` current code, in which I can detect the selected states, but still Unable to detect the focus states.

Here’s a part of the `DrawItem` current code, in which I can detect the selected states, but still Unable to detect the focus states.

```
void CXtabCtrl::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct) 
{
    CDC* pDC = CDC::FromHandle(lpDrawItemStruct->hDC);
    BOOL bFontSuccess = FALSE;
    CFont* def_font = NULL;
    CFont font_italic;

    TC_ITEM tci;
    CRect rect(lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem); 
    wchar_t szTabText[256]; 
    wmemset(szTabText,_T('\0'),256);

    RECT rectComplet; 
    GetClientRect(&rectComplet);
    CBrush brtmp(ColorCategoryBackgroundTop);
    int nbItem = GetItemCount();

    tci.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
    tci.pszText = szTabText;
    tci.cchTextMax = sizeof(szTabText) -1;
    GetItem(lpDrawItemStruct->itemID, &tci);

    BOOL bSelect = (lpDrawItemStruct->itemState & ODS_SELECTED) &&
                   (lpDrawItemStruct->itemAction & (ODA_SELECT | ODA_DRAWENTIRE));
    BOOL bfocus = (lpDrawItemStruct->itemState & ODS_FOCUS) &&
                  (lpDrawItemStruct->itemAction & (ODA_FOCUS | ODA_DRAWENTIRE));

    if (bSelect)//Draw In a Specific Way
    if (bFocus) //Draw In a Specific Way
}
```

So, I would be grateful if someone can describe the proper way to detect the two states of a CTabCtrl Item “Selected & Focused”, “Selected & But not focused”

Comment: The focus rectangle is drawn automatically for tab in dialogbox when you click the Alt tab. So you don't have to do anything! Just check `bSelect = (di->itemState & ODS_SELECTED);` to see if the item is selected. Check `bfocus = bSelect && (GetFocus() == this);` to see if the item has focus (but again, the focus rectangle is already drawn for you in ownerdraw tab control). You also want to check `ODS_NOFOCUSRECT` when focus rectangle is not requested.

Comment: Thank you for this describtion, but `BOOL bfocus = (lpDrawItemStruct->itemState & ODS_NOFOCUSRECT);` didn’t give the expected and it always gives `FALSE` as result.
However `if (pWinParent->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CWnd))) if (pWinParent->GetFocus() == this)` is giving me the result I’m looking for.
So thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For a standard tab control, the UI will not always draw the focus rectangle. To see the focus rectangle, the tab control must have `WS_TABSTOP` flag.

The focus rectangle will then be visible when user clicks the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to go through the dialog's controls, or when <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is pressed and tab control has focus.

The focus rectangle should be drawn automatically for owner draw tab control when applicable. Make sure `WS_TABSTOP` is set for tab control (in dialog editor, go to tab control's properties and set `"Tabstop = true"`)

`BOOL focused = selected && (GetFocus() == this);` will always be `TRUE` when user clicks on the tab control. `ODS_NOFOCUSRECT` will indicate if focus rectangle is not requested by the UI. See the example below.

Side note, `sizeof(szTabText)` returns the wrong value for `wchar_t`. Use `_countof(szTabText)` or `sizeof(szTabText)/sizeof(*szTabText)`

```
void CXtabCtrl::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT di)
{
    CDC* pDC = CDC::FromHandle(di->hDC);

    TC_ITEM tci;
    wchar_t text[256] = { 0 };
    tci.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
    tci.pszText = text;
    tci.cchTextMax = _countof(text);
    GetItem(di->itemID, &tci);

    BOOL selected = di->itemState & ODS_SELECTED;

    BOOL focused = selected && (GetFocus() == this);

    //The UI may not be drawing focus rectangle, even if we click on the tab
    if(di->itemState & ODS_NOFOCUSRECT)
        focused = FALSE;

    CString str;
    if(selected) str += L"SEL ";//indicate selected
    if(focused) str += L"FOC ";//indicate focused

    CRect rect(di->rcItem);
    pDC->TextOut(rect.left, rect.top, str);
}
```

[image]